# How to add groupname to a set of radiobuttonlist?

Tags: asp.net

I have a set of radiobuttonlist. Is it possible that I give all items a same group name so that there will be no multiple radiobutton selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

It should look something like:

```
<asp:RadioButton GroupName="MyRadiobuttons" />
```

Here's an msdn article on it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry that I didn't make it clear. Actually I have several RadioButtonLists instead of RadioButtons. Items in RadioButtonList don't have "GroupName" attribute.